# Implementing CKeditor's plugin

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I need to add the **Templates** plugin into Drupal8 CKeditor. So far it is available on the editor configuration page, but not on a node edit page. The code:

```
namespace Drupal\module_name\Plugin\CKEditorPlugin;

use Drupal\ckeditor\CKEditorPluginInterface;
use Drupal\ckeditor\CKEditorPluginButtonsInterface;
use Drupal\Component\Plugin\PluginBase;
use Drupal\editor\Entity\Editor;

class ContentTemplates extends PluginBase implements CKEditorPluginInterface, CKEditorPluginButtonsInterface {

  public function getButtons() {
    return array(
      'ContentTemplates' => array(
        'label' => t('Content templates'),
        'image' => drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name') . '/js/CKeditor/Plugin/templates/icons/templates.png',
        'image_rtl' => drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name') . '/js/CKeditor/Plugin/templates/icons/templates-rtl.png',
      ),
    );
  }

  public function isInternal() {
    return FALSE;
  }

  public function getDependencies(Editor $editor) {
    return array('dialog', 'dialogui');
  }    

  public function getLibraries(Editor $editor) {
    return array();
  }

  public function getFile() {
    return drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name') . '/js/CKeditor/Plugin/templates/plugin.js';
  }

  public function getConfig(Editor $editor) {
    return array();
  }

  // TODO: to be sure, should be removed and served by config
  function isEnabled(Editor $editor) {
    return TRUE;
  }
}
```

I also could see the methods injected by `templates/dialogs/templates.js` while inspecting the CKEditor object, but the file is not listed in the Chrome's resources inspector. I also don't see any code changes in this file takes effect (browser and drupal cache disabled, aggregation disabled).

Comment: I see you accepted an answer, but what from this answer helped you exactly? I'm facing the same issue with the `oembed` plugin, where it shows on the config page, but not on the node edit page, even though the Chrome console shows the Javascript Files were loaded.

Comment: Kimberly W, it was 4 years ago, sorry. I guess I missed the custom JS descriptor. You probably should check up-to-date documentation as it may change a lot, and probably become much better over time as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this two classes in *modules/custom/my_ckeditor/src/Plugin/CKEditorPlugin*:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_ckeditor\Plugin\CKEditorPlugin;

use Drupal\ckeditor\CKEditorPluginInterface;
use Drupal\Component\Plugin\PluginBase;
use Drupal\ckeditor\Annotation\CKEditorPlugin;
use Drupal\Core\Annotation\Translation;
use Drupal\editor\Entity\Editor;

/**
 * Defines the "templates" plugin.
 *
 * @CKEditorPlugin(
 *   id = "dialog",
 *   label = @Translation("CKEditor Dialog"),
 *   module = "ckeditor"
 * )
 */
class Dialog extends PluginBase implements CKEditorPluginInterface
{


  /**
   * Implements \Drupal\ckeditor\Plugin\CKEditorPluginInterface::getDependencies().
   */
  function getDependencies(Editor $editor)
  {
    return array();
  }



  /**
   * Implements \Drupal\ckeditor\Plugin\CKEditorPluginInterface::getLibraries().
   */
  function getLibraries(Editor $editor)
  {
    return array();
  }



  /**
   * Implements \Drupal\ckeditor\Plugin\CKEditorPluginInterface::isInternal().
   */
  function isInternal()
  {
    return false;
  }



  /**
   * Implements \Drupal\ckeditor\Plugin\CKEditorPluginInterface::getFile().
   */
  function getFile()
  {
    $plugin = drupal_get_path('module', 'my_ckeditor') . '/js/plugins/dialog/plugin.js';

    return $plugin;
  }



  /**
   * Implements \Drupal\ckeditor\Plugin\CKEditorPluginInterface::getConfig().
   */
  public function getConfig(Editor $editor)
  {
    return array();
  }
}



<?php

namespace Drupal\my_ckeditor\Plugin\CKEditorPlugin;

use Drupal\ckeditor\CKEditorPluginInterface;
use Drupal\ckeditor\CKEditorPluginButtonsInterface;
use Drupal\Component\Plugin\PluginBase;
use Drupal\ckeditor\Annotation\CKEditorPlugin;
use Drupal\Core\Annotation\Translation;
use Drupal\editor\Entity\Editor;

/**
 * Defines the "templates" plugin.
 *
 * @CKEditorPlugin(
 *   id = "templates",
 *   label = @Translation("CKEditor Templates"),
 *   module = "ckeditor"
 * )
 */
class Templates extends PluginBase implements CKEditorPluginInterface, CKEditorPluginButtonsInterface
{


  /**
   * Implements \Drupal\ckeditor\Plugin\CKEditorPluginInterface::getDependencies().
   */
  function getDependencies(Editor $editor)
  {
    return array('dialog');
  }



  /**
   * Implements \Drupal\ckeditor\Plugin\CKEditorPluginInterface::getLibraries().
   */
  function getLibraries(Editor $editor)
  {
    return array();
  }



  /**
   * Implements \Drupal\ckeditor\Plugin\CKEditorPluginInterface::isInternal().
   */
  function isInternal()
  {
    return false;
  }



  /**
   * Implements \Drupal\ckeditor\Plugin\CKEditorPluginInterface::getFile().
   */
  function getFile()
  {
    $plugin = drupal_get_path('module', 'my_ckeditor') . '/js/plugins/templates/plugin.js';

    return $plugin;
  }



  /**
   * Implements \Drupal\ckeditor\Plugin\CKEditorPluginInterface::getConfig().
   */
  public function getConfig(Editor $editor)
  {
    return array();
  }



  /**
   * Implements \Drupal\ckeditor\Plugin\CKEditorPluginInterface::getConfig().
   */
  public function getButtons()
  {
    return array(
      'Templates' => array(
        'label' => t('Templates'),
        'image' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_ckeditor') . '/js/plugins/templates/icons/templates.png',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The CKEditor plugins (Dialog & Templates) are placed in *modules/custom/my_ckeditor/js/plugins*

You also need a custom JS-file for your templates:

```
(function ($, Drupal, CKEDITOR) {
  "use strict";

  Drupal.behaviors.myCkeditor = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      var templates_path = '/modules/custom/my_ckeditor/templates/ckeditor/';

      var templates = [
        {
          title:       Drupal.t('Title'),
          description: Drupal.t('Description'),
          image:       'preview.gif',
          html:        'My Template'
        }
      ];

      // Remove default templates
      CKEDITOR.on("instanceLoaded", function () {
        CKEDITOR.config.templates_files = [];
      });

      // Load tempaltes
      CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function () {
        if (CKEDITOR.plugins.get('templates')) {
          CKEDITOR.config.templates_replaceContent = false;
          CKEDITOR.addTemplates('default', {
            imagesPath: templates_path,
            templates:  templates
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };

})(jQuery, Drupal, CKEDITOR);
```

This talk can help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=h9KV_VRvIG8#t=1965

Comment: How do you load the "custom JS-file for your templates"?

Comment: That talk did not help lol. "Hey btw here's some methods you can use to build the plugin, i'm not going to go into how you can use them. And here's some links that I'm not going to provide in the description!"

Answer (score 0):

The concept sunk in when I saw this: https://github.com/wwalc/moonocolor

Its the drupal8 implementation for moonocolor plugin of ckeditor

The only additions i could find are the 
.module file
.info.yml file

I did not find any reference to an extra js file.
Also in the above solution its not mentioned where the extra js file should be.

My efforts, not working yet
https://github.com/baverhey/d8_ckeditor_templates

Comment: The challenge with the moonocolor example is that it adds the CKeditor plugin to Drupal via hook_editor_js_settings_alter() and not as a Drupal plugin (using CKEditorPlugin).

Comment: You're telling me this minified js file helped you? https://github.com/wwalc/moonocolor/blob/master/js/skins/moonocolor/skin.js

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation at https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/ckeditor.

You can find examples in Drupal 8 core, at:

- `\Drupal\ckeditor_test\Plugin\CKEditorPlugin\Llama`
- `\Drupal\ckeditor_test\Plugin\CKEditorPlugin\LlamaButton`
- `\Drupal\ckeditor_test\Plugin\CKEditorPlugin\LlamaContextual`
- `\Drupal\ckeditor_test\Plugin\CKEditorPlugin\LlamaContextualAndButton`

Comment: Great link, thank you. It would help for those struggling with CKE. Glad to see the docs become more and more comprehensive.

Comment: Indeed! I spent many days shortly before the Drupal 8 release writing solid, comprehensive, clear docs on the modules/subsystems I maintain: http://wimleers.com/blog/drupal-8-release-day-docs. CKEditor is one of those. Let me know if you find an area that is lacking or unclear.

Comment: Dealing with this now and noticing that the js file from the module is being included, but the custom icon/folder is not being included in the sources tab in Chrome. Anyone ever resolve this?

Comment: I dont understand the example. It references drupal_get_path('module', 'ckeditor_test') . '/js/llama_button.js' which doesn't exist...