# CKEditor oEmbed Plugin Shows up in config but not in actual Editor instance

Tags: wysiwyg, plugins

The issue I'm having is very similar to [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/190324/custom-button-for-ckeditor-not-showing-up-in-node-creation-page), but the solutions here did not work for me.

The steps I took:

1. Downloaded the latest version of the oEmbed plugin from https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/oembed.
2. I extracted the `oembed` directory from the archive and placed that in a custom Drupal module that I already had. This module was used to create simple CKEditor button plugins and worked fine with them.
3. I went to the configuration page for `basic_html` and `full_html` editors and saw that the oEmbed button was one of the new options (`/admin/config/content/formats/manage/basic_html`).
4. I moved the oEmbed button to the "Active Toolbar" as well as some other custom plugins.
5. I went to edit some content where the WYSIWYG would show up
6. The other custom buttons showed up, but the oEmbed one did not, despite the fact that I could see it on the config page.

I've tried an older version of the oEmbed plugin from the download page, as well as clearing my cache many times with `drush cr`, but still no luck getting it to show up.

What's weird is that when I load the node edit page with the Chrome console open, I can see that *the Javascript/CSS for the oEmbed plugin is loading and executing*. The button icon though is never requested.

The Drupal Plugin looks like this

```
namespace Drupal\custom_ckeditor\Plugin\CKEditorPlugin;

/**
 * Defines the OEmbed plugin, with CKEditor.
 *
 * @CKEditorPlugin(
 *     id = "oembed",
 *     label = @Translation("OEmbed Plugin")
 * )
 */
class OEmbed extends extends PluginBase implements CKEditorPluginInterface, CKEditorPluginButtonsInterface
{
    protected $pluginName = 'oembed';

    public function getButtons()
    {
        $iconImage = $this->getIconPath();
        return [
            'OEmbed' => [
                'label' => t('Insert OEmbed'),
                'image' => $iconImage,
            ]
        ];
    }

    // Other required functions such as getLibraries() and getDependencies() all return an empty array or false and are omitted from this example.

}
```

I'm using Drupal 8, with CKEditor v4.7.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. On the Drupal side, everything was configured correctly. The error was in the Javascript. The original `plugin.js` file has the following:

```
editor.ui.addButton('oembed', {
                    label: editor.lang.oembed.button,
                    command: 'oembed',
                    toolbar: 'insert,10'
                });
```

I modified this to

```
editor.ui.addButton('OEmbed', {
                    label: editor.lang.oembed.button,
                    command: 'oembed',
                    toolbar: 'insert,10'
                });
```

Note the name passed to `addButton()` from `oembed` to `OEmbed`. I think there was some conflict in naming it `oembed`, possibly from some existing functionality. Not sure, but that was the fix for me.

In addition, I should note that for the *Basic Editor*, I had to modify the HTML filter to allow tags that the oEmbed plugin added to the source view. Hope this helps someone.