# Can't get Emoijone ckeditor plugin to appear on WSYISYG editor

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I am trying to add the Emojione CKEditor plugin on a Drupal 8.3.7 site. I've created a module using the CKEditor API. I modeled it after both the [youtube](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_youtube) and [smiley](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_smiley) CKEditor plugin modules.

In my custom module, I've added the file `src/Plugin/CKEditorPlugin/EmojioneCKEditorPlugin.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\emojione\Plugin\CKEditorPlugin;

use Drupal\ckeditor\CKEditorPluginBase;
use Drupal\editor\Entity\Editor;

/**
 * Defines the "emojione" plugin.
 *
 */
class EmojionePlugin extends CKEditorPluginBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getButtons() {
    return array(
      'Emojione' => array(
        'label' => t('emojione'),
        'image' => 'libraries/emojione/icons/emojione.png',
      ),
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFile() {
    return 'libraries/emojione/plugin.js';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function isInternal() {
    return FALSE;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getDependencies(Editor $editor) {
    return array();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getLibraries(Editor $editor) {
    return array();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getConfig(Editor $editor) {
    return array();
  }

}
```

The above is basically what both the ckeditor_youtube and ckeditor_smiley have. The relevant methods seem to be `getFile()` and `getButtons()`.

I have the relevant ckeditor plugin sources under `libraries/`.

When I enable my module and clear the cache and go to configure text formats and editors at `/admin/config/content/formats`, I don't see the emojione button, but I do have buttons for smiley and youtube.

I've found this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/139075/1441) and this [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/140902/1441), but in the answer, it isn't clear in what file the `Template` class goes. Also, the answerer mentions some custom js, but doesn't indicate where that goes either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add annotation for ckeditor plugin (more info about annotations based plugins [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/plugin-api/annotations-based-plugins)).

Youtube plugin is using this:

```
/**
 * Defines the "Youtube Button" plugin.
 *
 * @CKEditorPlugin(
 *   id = "youtube",
 *   label = @Translation("Youtube Plugin")
 * )
 */
class YoutubePlugin extends CKEditorPluginBase {
```

So you will need to add an annotation like this:

```
 /**
  * Defines the "Emojione" plugin.
  *
  * @CKEditorPlugin(
  *   id = "emojione",
  *   label = @Translation("Emojione")
  * )
  */
 class EmojionePlugin extends CKEditorPluginBase {
```

EDIT (thanks @kevin): clear caches after changes.

Comment: Yes, the annotation is required. Clear your cache after adding this.