# How to use custom Javascript inside Drupal8 CKEditor

Tags: 8, javascript, wysiwyg, plugins

I have a Javascript for tooltips and other things which work fine in front end but I want the same Javascript to run inside CKEditor too so that the user can see what he/she will get in the front end.
I have successfully linked my custom CSS with CKEditor using [function hook_ckeditor_css_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21ckeditor%21ckeditor.api.php/function/hook_ckeditor_css_alter/8.2.x)
which completes my half target but I didn't find any hooks for attaching custom Javascript.

Please share a tip or point me to any resource which may help in this regard. Thanks

Comment: You'll need to write a [custom ckeditor plugin](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample) to do that. Once you've done that, introducing it to Drupal is pretty easy: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/139075/implementing-ckeditors-plugin

Comment: @Clive I can't see in those links where the add a custom javascript. The only scripts they add are those which are needed by the plugin itself. I know this part of the stuff but I may be missing something seriously.

Comment: You probably don't need a plugin, actually, you can use [`CKEditor.scriptLoader`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.scriptLoader). I haven't personally used it so I can't help further I'm afraid

Comment: @Clive Thanks for the pointers. I will checkout your hints more deeply to see if they work out for me.